# If there are a way to get info at runtime about SparkMetrics configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-emr, metrics

I add metrics.properties file to resource directory (maven project) with CSV sinc. Everything is fine when I run Spark app locally - metrics appears. But when I file same fat jar to Amazon EMR I do not see any tries to put metrics into CSV sinc. So I want to check at runtime what are loaded settings for SparkMetrics subsystem. If there are any possibility to do this? 
I looked into `SparkEnv.get.metricsSystem` but didn't find any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is basically because Spark on EMR is not picking up your custom `metrics.properties` file from the `resources` dir of the fat jar.

For EMR the preferred way to configure is through [EMR Configurations API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-spark-configure.html) in which you need to pass the `classification` and `properties` in an embedded JSON.

- For `spark metrics` subsystem here is an example to modify a couple of metrics

```
  [
    {
      "Classification": "spark-metrics",
      "Properties": {
        "*.sink.csv.class": "org.apache.spark.metrics.sink.CsvSink",
        "*.sink.csv.period": "1"
      }
    }
  ]
```

You can use this JSON when creating EMR cluster using Amazon Console or through SDK